# Restore .bak database file on SQL Server without using SSMS? [DataGrip]

Tags: sql-server, database-restore, datagrip

Compared to SSMS, Datagrip doesn't really seem to have the "Restore Database"  option, so apparently the only way is through script.

I tried the following:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK = 'C:\Users\Marcelo\Downloads\Northwind.bak'
GO

RESTORE DATABASE Northwind
FROM DISK = 'C:\Users\Marcelo\Downloads\Northwind.bak'
WITH
  MOVE 'Northwind' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.LENOBRAC\MSSQL\DATA\Northwind.mdf',
  MOVE 'Northwind_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.LENOBRAC\MSSQL\DATA\Northwind_log.ldf',
GO
```

[2019-02-22 15:29:41] completed in 1 s 117 ms

The console shows that the task has been completed with no problems, however the database does not appear on the side explorer, I also cannot select any tables or do anything, I can only drop the database.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: ignore side explorer for a moment.  after restoring the database, execute this `USE Northwind`.  Do you get an error?

Comment: [2019-02-22 15:51:55] Database context changed to 'Northwind'.

[2019-02-22 15:51:55] completed in 2 ms

(I don't get any errors)

Comment: so the db was restored successfully. in that case, did you refresh the relevant explorers in SSMS?

Comment: It's not SSMS, but yeah i did refresh the explorer, without any luck

Answer (score 2):

Just try,

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE Northwind 
FROM  DISK = N'C:\Users\Marcelo\Downloads\Northwind.bak'
WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
GO
```

Comment: [2019-02-22 15:56:41] Error searching 'D:\MSSQLDataFiles\UNTC\DB_All\DB\NORTHWND.MDF' on the directories

Comment: Find out the correct path of your .bak file. As your question I copied the path. you should have correct the path

Comment: My Northwind.bak is on that same path [Users\Marcelo\Downloads\Northwind.bak]

Comment: Reason is already have the same .ldf and .mdf so that  you can rename or delete existing ldf and mdf and then run the script.

Comment: I don't have existing related .Idf and .mdf as i droped the database before trying this new method.

Answer (score -3):

- Right click on the hostname / datasource name in the explorer panel
- Go to database tools
- you'll find an option called manage shown schemas , just tick the
  mark next to databases you want to see